# How to access Apache Solr admin interface of Watson clusters

Tags: solr, ibm-watson

I couldn't find out a way by which I can access to Solr Admin interface.
Is it possible to access Admin interface of IBM Watson cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatly no, IBM Watson is a packaged version of solrcloud with some other functions.
Thus you will have to use Watson api to admin your Watson cluster. I would recommand to use the provided interface since, Watson is also managing some work for you. If you want to use solr admin, go out of watson and use native open source solr cloud. But you will loose some functions provided by Watson.

[You can have a look at watson API here.](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/#introduction)